# laravel and vue js using axios returns undefined when console.log() or viewed

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, undefined

here is my vue js file code that to fetch data.

```
axios.get('/api/course/subject/chapter', {})
    .then(res=>console.log(res.data.chapters))
    .catch(err => console.log(err.response))
```

This is my route api.

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth:api'],'namespace'=>'Admin'],function(){
    Route::resource('course/subject/chapter', 'ChapterController');
});
```

this is my controller

```
public function index()
{
    return response()->json(['chapters'=>Chapter::all()],200);
}
```

Comment: Please include the complete response that you are getting from your API

Comment: I am getting nothing I guess because data is viewed in console and it says undefined

Comment: My route was interfering with with other routes. I solved it. Thanks for your quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **{}**

```
.then(res => { console.log(res.data.chapters); })
.catch(err => { console.log(err.response.data); })
```

Comment: My other get requests are working fine the same as it is.. However I tried your solution but did't work for me.